# Magento - Display element on page load using scriptaculous and prototype

Tags: magento, scriptaculous

I have an element in my product list page that I want to hide until the rest of the document has finished loading. (it's a list item with the class "hideme") 
The JS solution doesn't work for me, so I'm looking for a scriptaculous method, which should work better in Magento.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make something client-side once the DOM has been loaded, you should try with this:
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  // initially hide all containers for tab content
  $$('div.tabcontent').invoke('hide');
});

Is more like jQuery(document).ready();

Greetings.

Comment: Thanks @Beto for your response. Could you please indicate where to put that code? This is what my code looks like now: `<li class="hideme"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist">+ Lista</a></li>` This is the item I need to hide until the rest of the document has finished loading. Thanks, this is my first try at scriptaculous and prototype ever.

Comment: First add a display none in your element and some id.
<li class="hideme"><a id="mylink" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist" style="display: none;>+ Lista</a></li>

Then at the end of your .phtml
<script>
document.observe("dom:loaded", function(){
$('mylink').show();
});
</script>

something like that, i havent tested yet, but you could try.

Comment: do you know how I could add a 1 second delay to the effect? Thanks again!